# Снять кадры с указанием времени

Tags: ffmpeg

Как можно снять 4 кадра с видео с указанием времени?

```
00:00:45
00:01:21
00:02:10
00:03:15
```

```
$output = shell_exec('/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i ' . $videoPath . ' -r 1 -ss 00:00:45 -vframes 1 -t 1 ' . $tmpPath . '/%09d.jpg 2>&1');
```

Команда снимает один кадр. Мне интересно можно ли снять 4 кадра в одном запросе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не поверите, но:

```
-vframes 4 -t 4
```

Comment: Интересно, автору ответ помог? :)